# JSON File issues

Tags: objective-c, json, serialization

So I'm making an urban planning app, and to start practicing with JSON I've made a simple file with the city name, three tallest buildings and the population... Here's what my JSON File looks like...

```
[{ "city" : "New York", "Buildings" : [ One World Trade Center, 432     Park Avenue, Empire State Building ], "pop" : 21,000,000 },
[{ "city" : "Chicago", "Buildings" : [ Sears Tower, Trump Tower, AON     Center ], "pop" : 9,000,000 },
[{ "city" : "Philadelphia", "Buildings" : [ Comcast Center, One Liberty     Place, Two Liberty Place ], "pop" : 6,000,000 }]
```

Everything is set up correctly with the table view and serialization code but I keep getting the error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be     completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 40.)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ Should explain where you're going wrong. Hint: quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to show your code, but it probably doesn't matter, because your data isn't properly-formatted JSON, which is likely the actual problem here. For one thing, some of your strings aren't quoted. For another, you have way more [ than ].